# Dynamically generated drop-down list from XML values

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, drop-down-menu, dynamically-generated

I have a form where users will be able to enter different pieces of information. One of the fields is "StudyCode". Once the user enter the study code, in another part of the report, the field "DrugName" will be dynamically populated with the list of drugs (drop down) that belong to that specific study.

Sample XML (druglist.xml):

```
<DrugList>
    <DrugCode Code="6995">
        <Name>Drug 1</Name>
        <Name>Drug 2</Name>
        <Name>Drug 3</Name>
    </DrugCode>
    <DrugCode Code="0130">
        <Name>Drug 4</Name>
        <Name>Drug 5</Name>
    </DrugCode>
    <DrugCode Code="3951">
        <Name>Drug 6</Name>
        <Name>Drug 7</Name>
        <Name>Drug 8</Name>
        <Name>Drug 9</Name>
    </DrugCode>
</DrugList>
```

Code so far (test.html):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script lang="Javascript">
   $.noConflict();
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var myField = $("#myList")
      var myOutputField = $("#myOutput").parent().parent().find("input");
      myOutputField.attr("readonly",true); 

      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "includes/DrugList.xml",
         dataType: "xml",
         success: parseXML
      });

      function parseXML(xml){
         $(xml).find("DrugCode").each(function(){
            myField.append($("<option />").val($(this).attr("Code")).text($(this).find("Name").text()));
         });
         myField.val(myOutputField.val());
      }

      myField.change(function(){
         myOutputField.val(myField.val());
         myOutputField.change();
      });
   });
</script><select id="myList">
```

What am I am doing wrong?

Comment: What isn't it doing that you expect it to?